Pytorch Embedding Layers RecSys
class RecommendationSystemModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_users,
        num_movies,
        embedding_size=128,
        hidden_dim=128,
        dropout_rate=0.2,
    ):
        super(RecommendationSystemModel, self).__init__()
        self.num_users = num_users
        self.num_movies = num_movies
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        # Embedding layers
        self.user_embedding = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings=self.num_users, embedding_dim=self.embedding_size
        )
        self.movie_embedding = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings=self.num_movies, embedding_dim=self.embedding_size
        )
        
        print(self.num_users, self.num_movies)

        # Hidden layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2 * self.embedding_size, self.hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, 1)

        # Dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout_rate)

        # Activation function
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, users, movies):
        # Embeddings
        user_embedded = self.user_embedding(users)
        movie_embedded = self.movie_embedding(movies)
        #print("User embedded shape:", user_embedded.shape)
        #print("Movie embedded shape:", movie_embedded.shape)

        # Concatenate user and movie embeddings
        combined = torch.cat([user_embedded, movie_embedded], dim=1)
        #print("Combined shape:", combined.shape)

        # Pass through hidden layers with ReLU activation and dropout
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(combined))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        output = self.fc2(x)

        return output


        return output


This is my RecSys model code. I used MovieLens 25M dataset with binary labels (ratings lower than 3 are considered as 0 where the ratings higher than 3 are considered as 1). I sampled 1M lines of the dataset. In my subsample number of user ids and movie ids are 12674, 20784 respectively. I am running my training on Kaggle P100 GPU. When I run this cell on Kaggle
recommendation_model = RecommendationSystemModel(
    num_users=12674, 
    num_movies=20784,
    embedding_size=128,
    hidden_dim=64,
    dropout_rate=0.1,
).to(device)

or this cell
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(recommendation_model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

EPOCHS = 2

# Function to log progress
def log_progress(epoch, step, total_loss, log_progress_step, data_size, losses):
    avg_loss = total_loss / log_progress_step
    sys.stderr.write(
        f"\r{epoch+1:02d}/{EPOCHS:02d} | Step: {step}/{data_size} | Avg Loss: {avg_loss:<6.9f}"
    )
    sys.stderr.flush()
    losses.append(avg_loss)

total_loss = 0
log_progress_step = 100
losses = []
train_dataset_size = len(df_train)
print(f"Training on {train_dataset_size} samples...")

recommendation_model.train()
for e in range(EPOCHS):
    step_count = 0  # Reset step count at the beginning of each epoch
    for i, train_data in enumerate(train_loader):
        output = recommendation_model(
            train_data["users"].to(device), train_data["movies"].to(device)
        )
        # Reshape the model output to match the target's shape
        output = output.squeeze()  # Removes the singleton dimension
        #print('train data clicks shape: ', train_data["clicks"].shape)
        ratings = (
            train_data["clicks"].to(torch.float32).to(device)
        )  # Assuming ratings is already 1D

        loss = loss_func(output, ratings)
        total_loss += loss.sum().item()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Increment step count by the actual size of the batch
        step_count += len(train_data["users"])

        # Check if it's time to log progress
        if (
            step_count % log_progress_step == 0 or i == len(train_loader) - 1
        ):  # Log at the end of each epoch
            log_progress(
                e, step_count, total_loss, log_progress_step, train_dataset_size, losses
            )
            total_loss = 0

I get the exception:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA to enable device-side assertions.
When I set
recommendation_model = RecommendationSystemModel(
    num_users=1_000_000, 
    num_movies=1_000_000,
    embedding_size=128,
    hidden_dim=64,
    dropout_rate=0.1,
).to(device)

where num_users and num_movies are equal, no exception occurs!
But once I get an exception, even if I changed the num_users and num_movies set to 1000000, I still get the exception! Never run into such problem before.
Any ideas?
I tried to create my model with different number of entries in terms of user ids and movie ids. I ended up with an exception. I want to solve it.
